# How to optimise this query using table join?

Tags: sql, optimization, join

can somebody please help me in optimising the following query...

```
UPDATE tab1 SET col1 = 'NA' where 
col2 =(Select col1 from tab2 where col2 is null and 
col3 = (Select col1 from tab3 where col2 = 100));
```

Comment: Please share sample data, I know it is not fully required, but can speed up my ans.

Comment: Just to note, depending on the amount of records you could further optimise the query by making sure that the reference columns are indexed. All depending on your data structure and amount of data of course.

Comment: You might find syntax differences depending on which DB this has to run on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update t1
SET col1 = 'NA'
from tab1 t1
inner join tab2 t2 on t1.col2=t2.col1 and t2.col2 is null
inner join tab3 t3 on t2.col3=t3.col1 and t3.col2 = 100
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but to get same result as the original query, shouldn't tab3 be joined to tab2 instead of tab1 ?